# Getting an error while uploading app into playstore about permissions related to camera

Tags: java, android, google-play

Your app has an apk with version code 1 that requests the following permission(s): android.permission.CAMERA. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set

Comment: you must provide privacy policy when your app uses permission like camera, storage etc..

Comment: You must host a page containig your privacy policy on a webserver and add the link to it in the store listing

Answer (score 0):

check all the links about the documentation of privacy policy

http://www.iubenda.com/blog/warning-google-play-developer-policy-violation-action-required-policy-issue/

http://www.iubenda.com/blog/privacy-policy-for-android-app/

https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/personal-sensitive/

**Add a privacy policy to your store listing**

1. Go to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. Select Store Listing.
4. Under "Privacy Policy," enter the URL where you have the privacy policy hosted online.
5. Select Save draft (new apps) or Submit update (existing apps).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a link to your hosted privacy policy, in the playstore console.

For more information, you should also take look at

1.this article [medium article on privacy policy](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/did-you-get-one-of-these-google-play-developer-policy-violation-emails-6c529ceb082d)

2.[Privacy Policy Generators](https://reviewsquirrel.com/best-privacy-policy-generators/)

3.[Six reasons why you must have a privacy policy](http://www.iubenda.com/en/mobile) [Scroll down and read though its a product (whom i dont work for :p)]